# Excel linking in perl

Tags: excel, perl

How can I read an excel file from a URL or through a link in Perl.

```
my $url = 'the link for the excel file';
my $data = get $url;
die "No data found\n" unless defined $data;
my @record = split /\n/, get($url);
```

Comment: Welcome at SO, @harshpanwar!
What

Comment: _sorry, ENTER came too fast_
Welcome at SO, @harshpanwar!

It depends on what you want to do with the file content.
I guess, you have `LWP::Simple` installed.
`$data` contains whatever the GET request returns (Hence you could omit the second request in the last line).
If your EXCEL file actually is a *.csv file, the last line may work, and would return
an array containing its lines. In case of an *.xls, or *.xlsx file, the result might not be what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [LWP::Simple](http://p3rl.org/LWP::Simple) to download a file from a link.

To process an Excel file, use [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](http://p3rl.org/Spreadsheet::ParseExcel), [Spreadsheet::Read](http://p3rl.org/Spreadsheet::Read), or [Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX](http://p3rl.org/Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX).

Comment: I used the library but it shows data not found    use LWP::Simple;

my $url = 'link for excel file';
my $data = get $url;
die "No data found\n" unless defined $data;
my @record = split /\n/, get($url);

Comment: As suggested in the docs, use [LWP::UserAgent](http://p3rl.org/LWP::UserAgent) to get details about failed requests.